# didReceiveApplicationContext method in background WatchOS/WatchConnectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

I calling updateApplicationContext method in AppDelegate in order to check and send user name to Apple Watch.

```
NSDictionary *applicationDict = @{@"status" : m.customer.first_name};
[[WCSession defaultSession] updateApplicationContext:applicationDict error:nil];
```

When watch app is in background and iOS app wakes up. updateApplicationContext method in iOS is called and didReceiveApplicationContext method is called in WatchOS. However, I can not set text of label when didReceiveApplicationContext is called when Watch app is in the background. If watch app is active when didReceiveApplicationContext is called then text of label is changed.

Delegate method in watchOS:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]){
        let message : String = applicationContext["status"] as! String
        messageLabel.setText(message)
    }
```

What can be reason of the problem? Should I keep the value that is fetched when the watch app is in the background and change the text when willActivate is called?

Answer (score 0):

Put your

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]){
    let message : String = applicationContext["status"] as! String
    messageLabel.setText(message)
}
```

Method in the Extension Delegate to catch Updates if App is in Background or in ViewController when is active. 
I had a same issue turns out that the didReceiveApplicationContext Method gets called as expected. But then testing it sometimes it need a few seconds to get data in background. So I sometimes started my App and was confused that the label didn't update. Problem was that data get delivered after the View Controller went active.